# Proof of a particular solution for a non homogeneus linear differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $L(y)=y′′+ay′+by$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, let $f$ be the particular solution of $L(y)=0$ satisfying the conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f′(0)=1$. Show that a particular solution of $L(y)=R$ is given by the formula $y_1(x)=∫^x_cf(x−t)R(t)dt$ for any choice of $c$.

***My attempt:***
Let $c=0$,
$$y_1'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}∫^x_0f(x−t)R(t)dt$$
By the Leibniz integral rule

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}∫^x_0f(x−t)R(t)dt&=\: f(x-x)R(x)\cdot x'-f(x-0)R(0)\cdot 0+\int_0^x [f'(x-t)R(t)+f(x-t)\frac{d R(t) }{dx}]dt\\
&=f(0)R(x)+\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)R(t)dt\\
&\underbrace{=}_{f(0)=0}\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)R(t)dt
\end{align*}
Then $y_1'(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)R(t)dt$.

Again, for the Leibniz rule
\begin{align*}
y_1''(x)&=f'(0)R(x)+\int_0^x f''(x-t)R(t)dt\\
&\underbrace{=}_{f'(0)=1} R(x)+\int_0^x f''(x-t)R(t)dt.
\end{align*}

Replacing $y_1$, $y_1'$, $y_1''$ in $y′′+ay′+by=R$, I got

$\displaystyle R(x)+\int_0^x f''(x-t)R(t)dt+a\left(\int_{0}^{x}f'(x-t)R(t)dt\right)+b\left(∫^x_cf(x−t)R(t)dt\right)=R(x),$
$\displaystyle \int_0^x \left(f''(x-t)+af'(x-t)+b f(x-t)\right)\: R(t)dt=0 \:\:\:(1)$

***My questions:***

- First, could you tell me if what I've done is correct and also the
  justifications are alright?
- Second: I'm stuck in (1), I don't know how to proceed any further. I
  was thinking that since $f''(x)+af'(x)+bf(x)=0$, I could replace in (1), but there I have $f''(x-t)+af'(x-t)+bf(x-t)=0$, but maybe it could, since $x-t$ and $x$ are mute variables.

Thanks in advance.